# Play: obtaining a connection to the default database

Tags: playframework-2.0

I would like to obtain a connection to the Database instance that I define when I write this in *application.conf*:

```
db.default {
  driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"
  username = ...
  password = ...
}
```

The [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDatabase#Obtaining-a-JDBC-connection) say that we should inject `db: Database` into a controller (which works fine), **and shows no other way**. The predefined Guice injection for that is hidden (not in *Module.scala*). Also it suggests that a default Database singleton is created automatically by Play.

What if I don't want to inject the database into a controller, but separate concerns and use it only in some `SqlHandler` object which only job is to do SQL queries:

```
object SqlHandler {
  val db: Database = ???
  def select(params) {...db...}
  def insert(params) {...db...}
}
```

I know that I can create a new Database instance with [`play.api.db.Databases`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.db.Databases$) with something like

```
import play.api.db.Databases
val db: Database = Databases(
  driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"
  username = ...
  password = ...
)
```

but not only do I find stupid to repeat all the information, I believe it also creates the Database twice (once automatically, once here manually, doesn't it?).

Is there any convenience method to obtain a connection to my default Database, or *how* can I use Guice to inject it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes you want to inject your `SqlHandler` into a controller.

If so, you can just do this in your controller:-

```
class Application @Inject() (sql: SqlHandler) extends Controller {

  def index = Action { implicit request =>
    ...    
    sql.someSQLHandlerBehaviour()
    ...
  }
}
```

Since controllers are managed by Guice out-of-the-box, any injectables will also fall within the scope of Guice's life-cycle management. So you should just be able to inject your `SqlHandler` into a controller as above.

And since your `SqlHandler` is now under the management of Guice, you can inject the `jdbc` dependencies into `SqlHandler` like so.

```
@Singleton
class SqlInjector @Inject() (db: Database) { ... }
```

Comment: Sorry I really still don't get it. It is `SqlHandler` that I want to use the db in, not some new `DBTest`.

Comment: Hi, it was just an example. I edited my post though for clarity. The important bit is that you (A) Understand that you can inject dependencies anywhere, as long as the injector and injectee are managed by Guice. (B) If you only want a single instance you can use `@Singleton` on the class rather than trying to inject into an `object` - which will require more mileage.

Comment: All right. And now I should inject SqlHandler (anywhere) instead of Database, am I right? If I just do `new SqlHandler` it complains that it requires a Database parameter.

Comment: I can inject the Database in SqlHandler, but I can't do `new SqlHandler` without providing it with a Database as argument ("Not enough arguments for constructor SqlHandler. Unspecified value parameter db"), so I'm stuck again :s Sorry for being so slow.

Comment: Julian, I just double checked a working example and edited my previous answer since it was a bit misleading. I'm using Play 2.5.8. Basically, the whole point to DI is that you do not instantiate any dependencies yourself, the framework provides them ie. no doing `new SqlHandler`, you inject it and this will be a instance ready to be used.