# Instantiate default database play framework

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework

I'm using Play 2.5 with Scala. I want to move away from run-time dependency injection to compile time DI.

Today, I have the following:

```
@Singleton
class ScoringControllerDB @Inject()(@NamedDatabase("default") db: Database
                                    ,model:predictiveModels.PMML.ModelScorerTrait
                                   ) extends Controller {
```

Now, I want to move that to `AppComponents`, following the article [here](https://jaxenter.com/compile-time-dependency-injection-play-framework-130409.html) .

it will now logically look like this:

```
@Singleton
class ScoringControllerDB (db: Database, model : predictiveModels.PMML.ModelScorerTrait
                                   ) extends Controller {
```

However, I have the hardest time figuring out how to instanciate `db = Database` with my default database (in application.conf) to replace what I get.

Any input ?

PS: Looking at this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075706/play-obtaining-a-connection-to-the-default-database), it looks like I should not be instantiating it. Is this correct ?

Thanks !

Comment: I have a simple example working here, maybe it helps: https://github.com/pedrorijo91/play-slick3-steps/tree/play2.5

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using Scala's anorm and not slick.